# ECU leaks current

Tags: electrical, battery, electronic-control-module, electronics, kawasaki

Im the proud owner of an ER-6F from 2009.
I just tested my bike for leaking current and noticed it did. When pulling the fuses I found the ECU to be the culprit. I assume this is not normal. What do i need to do?
[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Welcome.  Start by telling us exactly which bike it is.  Also do you have the wiring diagram for the bike?

Comment: It's an ER-6F from 2009. I have the wiring diagrams In my haynes book. Just added it to the post

Comment: Thanks for adding the wiring diagram.  Which numbered fuse did you pull?

Comment: On the fuse box it says "15A ECU". Which i believe is "F3 Engine Management" on the diagram.

Comment: The wiring diagram indicated that fuse 3 supplies the instrument cluster, the ECU and the ECU main relay.  I would start by unplugging those individually to find out which one is drawing the current.

Comment: When unplugging what i believe is the starter relays the multimeter reads zero (image added to main post)

Comment: If I'm reading the multimeter correct its leaking 0.20mA. I just heard from someone that that's normal? Is this correct?

Comment: Disconnecting the starter relay would disconnect power to everything other than the ABS system, so it is likely to drop the current to zero.  It is plausible for 20mA to be normal.  I would still suggest you disconnect the components I suggested earlier.

Comment: What would belong to the instrument cluster? Like the dash?

Comment: Yes, the dashboard.

Comment: Ill try to disconnect it this evening. Are there other parts to the instrument cluster?

Comment: looks pretty normal to me

Comment: Awesome, that's exactly what I hoped to hear hahahah

Comment: It was indeed the dashboard, ill assume to keep the clock running